# Get values from multiple input fields generated by #each in meteor and insert them in collection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, meteor

Having some troubles in meteor forms

The user can add input fields by clicking a + button.
After the "save" button is clicked the values in the input fields should be updated in the collection.

HTML:

```
<template name="EditQuestion">
<form id="updateQuestion">


    {{#each option}}
        <li><input name="Option"  type="text" placeholder="Answer Option" class="answerOption"></li></button>   
    {{/each}}

<button type="submit" id="submitQuestion" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form></template>
```

JS:

```
Template.EditQuestion.events({
"submit #updateQuestion"(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    var options = target.Option;
    console.log(options);
    console.log(options.value);
}});
```

the first console.log generates the a RadioNodeList[]
the second is empty

How can i access the values in options and insert them in my collection?

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLkSV.png)

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90yLM.png)

Comment: The second is empty because your options is an Array (or at least Array like), so you should check them by using `options[0].value`

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to associate each stamped out template item with a piece of data. i have not found a better way to do this than the below...

```
{{#each option}}
    <li><input name="Option" data-value="option._id" type="text" placeholder="Answer Option" class="answerOption"></li></button>   
{{/each}}


'submit #updateQuestion': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // omg there has to be a better way to find this!
    if (event && event.currentTarget && event.currentTarget.dataset) {
        let optionData = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
        console.log(optionData);
    }
}
```

for each of the options, i assigned its id to a "value" field that i looked up in the JS. if i ever find a better way of doing this, i will look up all the "omg" comments in the code and fix it!